# How to fix sync issues or corrupted profile in a Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I had a problem with my Chromebook with a corrupted profile.

First, whenever I logged in, it would attempt to load my profile, but since it was corrupted, the Chrome browser kept crashing immediately, then it would log me out. This occurred even after powerwashing (wiping) all accounts.

Later, somehow it got to a slightly better state where it didn't crash immediately, but it gave the message: "Chrome OS could not sync your data because your account sign-in details are out of date". Logging out, rebooting, powerwashing still didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do a Chrome Sync Reset from another browser.

Go to your Chrome Sync page https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync (logged in with the corresponding Google account).

Click `Reset Sync` at the bottom of the page.

On the Chromebook, try logging in again.